# Conditionals, event handling, binding not working after AJAX call

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm making an AJAX call during the 'beforeCreate' life cycle and updating the data variables with the received data. I'm able to interpolate the data using the v-for this way. However, conditionals, event handling, binding do not work within this context.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [],
    isVisible: []
  },
  beforeCreate: function() {
    var vm = this;
    // make ajax call
    // on done
    .done(function(res) {
      // do some validation
      vm.items = res.itemList;  
      for (var i = 0; i < vm.items.length; i++) {
        vm.isVisible.push(false) // initialize to false
      }

    }) 
  }
)}
```

In the html I want to do something like this:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <img :src="item.imgURL1" v-if="isVisible[index]">
  <img :src="item.imgURL2" v-else>
  <button @click="isVisible[index] = !isVisible[index]>Toggle</button>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how I can implement something like this?

Answer (score 0):

To get index when using v-for, [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Basic-Usage) supports an optional second argument for the index of the current item: the sysntz is like this

```
v-for="(item, index) in items"
```

As par the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Basic-Usage), make changes like following:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <img :src="item.imgURL1" v-if="isVisible[index]">
  <img :src="item.imgURL2" v-else>
  <button @click="isVisible[index] = !isVisible[index]>Toggle</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I have the v-for setup like you suggested. Just forgot to write it when I was coming up with the code example. This doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Grant still you are using `isVisible[i]` not `isVisible[index]`? Any error you are getting? is `items` populate properly and you can get it in HTML like this `{{items}}` ?

Comment: yes, i'm able to populate the values in the items array no problem.

Comment: @Grant And similarly `isVisible` data array is also properly populated?

Comment: Yes, isVisible array is also interpolated just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Turns out this caveat was already discussed in VueJS docs. Sorry for posting the questions without first going through the docs in detail. For anyone who comes across this post having the same problem, the answer can be found at: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Just had to use the `Vue.set()` method in the for loop section of above code example.

```
for (var i = 0; i < vm.items.length; i++) {
  Vue.set(vm.isVisible, i, false) // intialize to false            
}
```

Comment: Please add the code sample as well which helped you resolved the issue along with the link so that it can help others, Links should be used as reference.

Comment: I fixed the answer with where I should have used the Vue.set() method.